# Regular Expression to get img tag where src contains text

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

Using VB.net, I have a string that contains HTML. The HTML has several img tags within it. I am trying to grab an entire particular img tag based on the src containing specific characters (image002) so that I can replace the entire image tag with some new code.

What I have so far:

```
dim bodyContent as string = "<html><body><img src='image001.png'/><img src='image002.png'/></body></html>"
dim searchStr as string = "image002"

Dim imgRegex As New Regex("@""<img.*?src=""(?" & searchStr & ".*?)"".*?>""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
bodyContent = imgRegex.Replace(bodyContent, "<div class='newCode'><a href='https://mywebsite.net/ViewAttachment'><img src='https://mywebsite.net/ViewThumbnail'></a></div>")
```

However, my RegEx is not correct. Any advice on to get the correct RegEx?

Comment: Why did you put the C# verbatim string literal into the VB.NET string literal? Only use the string pattern. What is `(?` for?

Comment: I'm not sure- that's why I'm asking for help. I'm not experienced with Regular Expressions. It's just something I found in my attempt to google before asking this question.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Z2KwGf, I think you need `Dim imgRegex As New Regex("<img(?:\s+[^>]*?)?\ssrc='" & searchStr & "[^']*'[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: It was giving me some errors. After some adjusting based on your first comment, I got it to work with this:  `Dim imgRegex As New Regex("<img[^>]+" & searchStr & ".*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it mean you have a different input string? Please edit the question. Note `"<img[^>]+" & searchStr & ".*?>"` might find `searchStr` outside of `img` tag as `.` matches any char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```vb
Dim imgRegex As New Regex("<img[^>]+" & searchStr & "[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

The regex matches

- `<img` - `<img` string
- `[^>]+` - one or more chars other than `>`
- `& searchStr &`  - the literal text inside `searchStr` (note it works here like that because the variable only contains word chars, in a generic case, you need to escape it using `Regex.Escape(searchStr)`)
- `[^>]*>` - zero or more chars other than `>` and then a `>` char.

Full [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/XjCuBg):

```vb
Dim bodyContent as string = "<html><body><img src='image001.png'/><img src='image002.png'/></body></html>"
Dim searchStr as string = "image002"
Dim imgRegex As New Regex("<img[^>]+" & searchStr & "[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
bodyContent = imgRegex.Replace(bodyContent, "<div class='newCode'><a href='https://mywebsite.net/ViewAttachment'><img src='https://mywebsite.net/ViewThumbnail'></a></div>")
Console.Write(bodyContent)
```

Output:

```vb
<html><body><img src='image001.png'/><div class='newCode'><a href='https://mywebsite.net/ViewAttachment'><img src='https://mywebsite.net/ViewThumbnail'></a></div></body></html>
```